# HTML Editable P Which updates MySQL DB

Tags: php, html, mysql, tags

I would like to implement an editable "p" element which will update a corresponding table of a database after the user presses enter or is done editing the information (Similar to how the newest version of phpmyadmin works.)

I would like to avoid using javascript and use strictly php/html.

Does anyone know how can be done or could point me in the direction of a tutorial or site discussing this topic?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do what you'd like to do without some `Javascript`, unless you're fine with using traditional HTML forms and requesting an entirely new page for every update.

["`AJAX`"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) is the technique being applied in phpMyAdmin (and anywhere you see "live" changes, without the page being refreshed.

Additionally, `paragraph` (`<p/>`) elements aren't editable input fields.

Comment: You can use the [`contenteditable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Content_Editable) attribute to make almost anything editable, but JavaScript is still required to submit it.

Comment: Huh... I've never seen that before nor can I think where I'd use it :) Thanks for the education thou, @rink.attendant.6!

Comment: paragraphs are editable fields see here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_contenteditable.asp

Comment: Sounds like I will have to use Javascript then. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

how about using AngularJS and extending the following to write back to the DB:

http://tamaspiros.co.uk/2013/05/28/inline-editing-with-angularjs/

Comment: OP doesn't want to use JS :(

Comment: I don't think you'd be able to write (send) data only using html and php (and without a page refresh)